# How to properly unload Unity WebGL when component is removed by Router in React

Tags: reactjs, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I am wondering if someone implemented Unity web Gl to the website developed in React. That’s what I do now, and started to regret my choice.

Everything works fine, but for about two weeks I can’t solve one problem.

The problem occurs when I am navigating away from the page, and it seems after all the game still works behind th scene. My guess is that it wasn’t properly unloaded. It’s only terminated when page is refreshed or navigated in old fashioned way.

I tried to use react’s useEffect hook to recognize when user is leaving the page (component is removed) but when I do, unload() function tells that unity game wasn’t instantiated (the game music still plays in the background anyway).

I wouldn’t like to solve this problem the tricky way by using seperate page for the game as purpose of React is to work as a single page application.

Thank you for all the answers in advance.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { Unity, useUnityContext } from "react-unity-webgl";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import DelayLink from "react-delay-link";

import "./styles/UnityGame.css";

const UnityGame = (props) => {
  const { unityProvider, requestFullscreen, unload, isLoaded } =
    useUnityContext({
      loaderUrl:
        "../../" + props.gameName + "/" + props.gameName + ".loader.js",
      dataUrl: "../../" + props.gameName + "/" + props.gameName + ".data",
      frameworkUrl:
        "../../" + props.gameName + "/" + props.gameName + ".framework.js",
      codeUrl: "../../" + props.gameName + "/" + props.gameName + ".wasm",
      webglContextAttributes: {
        preserveDrawingBuffer: true,
      },
    });

  const iframeRef = useRef();
  const unityFrameRef = useRef();

  var firstLog = false;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("use effect content:");
    return () => {
      if (iframeRef !== null) {
        if (firstLog) {
          console.log("CleanUp function called");
          /*unload();*/
          window.document
            .getElementById("iframeContainer")
            .removeChild(iframeRef.current);
        }

        firstLog = true;
        if (firstLog) {
          console.log("first log activated");
        }
      }
    };
  }, []);

  function handleClickEnterFullscreen() {
    requestFullscreen(true);
  }

  function takeMeAway() {
    unload();
    console.log("clickAction invoked");
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div id="iframeContainer" ref={iframeRef}>
        <Unity
          unityProvider={unityProvider}
          style={{ width: 960, height: 540 }}
          ref={unityFrameRef}
        />
      </div>
      <button onClick={handleClickEnterFullscreen}>Enter Fullscreen</button>;
      <button>Close Game</button>;
      <DelayLink delay={2000} to="/" clickAction={takeMeAway} replace={false}>
        <p>Hello, I'm a clickable link.</p>
      </DelayLink>
      <Link to="/"></Link>
    </>
  );
};

export default UnityGame;
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I got it working in my previous project is to use an *<iframe>*, inside which the game runs. Keep a reference to it in the state of the component (for example [using refs](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)).

Then in the return value of the useEffect hook, remove it from the DOM manually. You can use something like this :

```
useEffect(() => {
    ...
    return () => {
            if (iframeRef !== null)
                window.document.body.removeChild((iframeRef.current);
        };
});
```

Comment: It seems like iframe created for this purpose is actually null when I am trying to remove child from it. What I realised is, when I used delayed navigation, and called unload() function on onClick() event, everything just worked perfectly, but it's still not the perfect solution for me. So far I think unload() function is called a little bit to late and references are actually removed while I am trying to close the game.